# Printing the factors of 2-100 in java

Tags: java

I am trying to minimize the iteration so I used `j<=i/j` in the 2nd `for loop`. The code is working but I can't get the full output. I mean factors of 6 are 2 and 3, but it is only printing 2.

Can anyone help me? I am a beginner.

```
class factors{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int i,j;
        for(i=2;i<=100;i++){
            System.out.print("\nFactors of "+i+" : ");
            for(j=2; j <= i/j; j++){
                if((i%j)==0){
                    System.out.print(j+" ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you also print `i/j`.

Comment: @laune how? it is not printing. it is for minimizing the iteration

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

After:

```
System.out.print(j+" ");
```

Add:

```
System.out.print((i/j)+" ");
```

The point of iterating until `i/j` is because the factors come in pairs, `j` and `i/j`, and you only need to iterate over half of them, and the others can be calculated from the ones you find.

Answer (score 1):

You get an unexpected output because `i/j` will be evaluated every iteration of the loop.

When `j=2`, `i/j` is 3, so the condition is true, and the first iteration of the loop runs. The next iteration, `j=3`, `i/j` is 2, which less than `j`, the condition is false, so the loop terminates there, without running the second iteration.

I think what you meant to say is `i / 2`. So change `i/j` to `i/2`.

Comment: Yes. thank you. i hope every beginners will make these kind of silly mistakes.

Comment: and will it minimize the amount of iterations?

Comment: @JayarajRohan It will iterate `i/2 - 1` times. I think this is what you intended

Comment: Well, the original version has the minimum amount of iterations. It is sqrt(i) times. You must just handle the fact that you find 2 factors at a time: j and i/j

Comment: @Henry can you explain it further?

Comment: See the answer by fgb.

Comment: @JayarajRohan Basically, my solution loops only half of `i` times instead of `i` times. However, Henry is saying that you can just loop for `sqrt(i)` times, like fgb did in his/her answer, because you find factors in pairs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(j=2; j <= i/j; j++)
```

Let run the code for i=6

So first it intialize j to 0 and then
`J<=6/2` so it it true because `2<=3`

But on next iteration
`J=3` and then
`J<=6/3` in this it is not true because `3<=2`

So change the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j=2; j <= i/j; j++){
    if((i%j)==0){
        System.out.print(j+" ");
    }
}
```

There are two problems in this code.

First, you only print one factor (`j`) when you find pairs (both `j` and `i/j`).  Already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501562/6660678).

Second, fixing that by printing `j` and `i/j` breaks the result for perfect squares, where `j` and `i/j` are the same (equal).  It prints the square root as a factor twice.  To fix that, you can stop the loop before you test a perfect square.  Then you can test for that special case outside the loop.

```
for (j = 2; j < i/j; j++) {
    if ((i%j) == 0) {
        System.out.print(j + " " + i/j + " ");
    }
}

if (j * j == i) {
    System.out.print(j);
}
```

Another alternative would be to check if `j` and `i/j` were equal before printing `i/j`.  Something like

```
System.out.print(j + " ");
if (j != i/j) {
    System.out.print(i/j + " ");
}
```

But that requires more checks than is necessary, because equality will only happen once per the loop.  But you have to check once for every factor pair that you find.